# How to access/change an ArrayList from tester class?

Tags: java, arraylist

this one has had me stuck for the last few hours, im trying to figure out how to access an arraylist of book objects stored in a "Library" class from my tester class, i do have getters and setters but i cant figure out how i access them from the tester class. Here is my code.

book.java

```
public class Book {
private int id;
private String bookTitle;
private String authorName;
private double bookReleaseYear;
private int numOnLoan;
private int numInStock;

//constructor
public Book(int id, String bookTitle, String authorName, double bookReleaseYear, int numOnLoan, int numInStock) {
    this.id = id;
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    this.authorName = authorName;
    this.bookReleaseYear = bookReleaseYear;
    this.numOnLoan = numOnLoan;
    this.numInStock = numInStock;
}
//getters
//setters
```

Library.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Library {

public ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

//Constructor
public Library(ArrayList<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}
//Getters/setters

public ArrayList<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(ArrayList<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}
```

LibraryTester.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LibraryTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Library<Book> book1 = new Library();
}
```

Ive been googling this for hours unless ive just happened to miss it, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `Library book1 = new Library(new ArrayList<Book>());` ?

Comment: That worked great Lashane, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access list of Book likewise,

```
public class LibraryTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Library library= new Library();
    ArrayList<Book> listOfBooks = library.getBooks();

}
```

**EDITED**

*Add following constructor into Library class,*

```
public Library(){
  super();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate the idea but its still telling me that "the  constructor 'library()' is undefined"

Comment: Thanks very much Vishal, youre a genius, both yours and Lashanes' methods seemed to work but you have both saved me many more hours of frustration. have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
Library library = new Library();
ArrayList<Book> books = library.getBooks();
Book book1 = books.get(0); //zero being the first index in the books array
```

That should get you what you need, assuming I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i still seem to get the same error which says "The constructor 'library' is undefined" I'm trying to access the arraylist in the 'library' class from the 'library tester' class

Comment: Aha! You don't have a default constructor.  which would be: public Library(){}.  Your constructor requires a books array to be passed in.  Which means in your test class you will need to create a Book object, and then add it to some ArrayList<Book> object, then pass that ArrayList into Library library = new Library(books);

Comment: Thank you Kyle, i think im understanding where i went wrong, I appreciate the help :)